# How can I pass a Graphics variable from the main class to the method and still be able to use it?

Tags: java, graphics, awt

I'm trying to make a line in my "Bar" class, but I'm not sure what to pass to the "draw" method from the main class. When I try to pass a "Graphics" variable to the method, it gives me an error.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class CodeMain extends Applet {

    static String inputZipCode = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter 5-digit Zip Code:");
    static int firstDigit = Integer.parseInt(inputZipCode.substring(0,1));
    static int secondDigit = Integer.parseInt(inputZipCode.substring(1,2));
    static int thirdDigit = Integer.parseInt(inputZipCode.substring(2,3));
    static int fourthDigit = Integer.parseInt(inputZipCode.substring(3,4));
    static int fifthDigit = Integer.parseInt(inputZipCode.substring(4,5));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bar barGraphic = new Bar();

        int checkDigit = zipCodeDigits.findCheckDigit(inputZipCode);

        String firstDigitCode = zipCodeDigits.digitCode(firstDigit);
        String secondDigitCode = zipCodeDigits.digitCode(secondDigit);
        String thirdDigitCode = zipCodeDigits.digitCode(thirdDigit);
        String fourthDigitCode = zipCodeDigits.digitCode(fourthDigit);
        String fifthDigitCode = zipCodeDigits.digitCode(fifthDigit);
        String checkDigitCode = zipCodeDigits.digitCode(checkDigit);

        barGraphic.draw(firstDigitCode);
    }

}




import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;

public class Bar {

    void draw (Graphics g, String digitCode) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

        Line2D.Double bar = new Line2D.Double(50, 50, 30, 30);
        g2.draw(bar);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the error? Please include the stack trace.

Comment: You don't actually have a `Graphics` variable to pass.  You can't draw on nothing.

Comment: Go over [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html). It's a Swing based tutorial (not AWT like, you're using) but 1. you'll find it useful, and 2. You should be using Swing anyway.